# Why does JQuery close the element if it finds forward slash "/>" in an attribute?

Tags: jquery, html

Using query to set HTML of an element to:

`<div data-mine="/>">content</div>`

Results in an extra closing tag inserted into the attribute

`<div data-mine="></div>">content</div>`

From read ing any specifications I can find, there is no encoding issue here. Why does jQuery behave this way, when setting the content using native DOM functions work fine.

Here is a snippet that demonstrates the difference between jQuery and native.

```js
$('#native')[0].innerHTML = "<div data-h='/>'>native</div>"
$('#jquery').html("<div data-h='/>'>jquery</div>")


$('#sourceraw').text($('#source').html())
$('#nativeraw').text($('#native').html())
$('#jqueryraw').text($('#jquery').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Elements</h2>

<p>HTML set with <code>data-</code> value of <code>"/&gt;"</code></p>

<div id="source"><div data-h='/>'>source</div></div>
<div id="native"></div>
<div id="jquery"></div>

<h2>Resulting Inner HTML</h2>

<h3>native</h3>
<pre id="nativeraw"></pre>
<h3>source</h3>
<pre id="sourceraw"></pre>
<h3>jquery</h3>
<pre id="jqueryraw"></pre>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's jQuery that is doing this? Browsers tend to 'fix' HTML in the way they see as logical. Does the same happen when using vanilla JS?

Comment: @Bram Vanroy: What's there to fix in `<div data-mine="/>">content</div>`? As the asker has shown, this does *not* happen when using innerHTML directly.

Comment: ... which makes this even stranger as, according to the jQuery docs, .html() uses innerHTML internally.

Comment: @BoltClock What I meant was that it is plausible that a browser sees `/>` and (wrongly) assumes it is part of a closing tag, so it tries to fix it. The same happens when adding a superfluous opening tag for instance.

Comment: jQuery does some additional things that innerHTML dosn't, for example it evaluates js inside the html, looks like this is a bug.

Comment: @Bram Vanroy: Ah, I see.

Comment: Perhaps someone who has more time on their hands can go through all additional function calls in the [`html()` function](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=html). Is it perhaps this line?: `value = value.replace(rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>");`

Comment: @Bram Vanroy: Probably. Of course jQuery makes a blanket assumption that the argument to .html() uses XHTML syntax, despite its name...

Comment: @BoltClock do you have any references for the XHTML statement?

Comment: @tpower: I'm just hazarding a guess based on the fact that the variable holding the replacement pattern in that line of code is called `rxhtmlTag`.

Comment: @BramVanroy good spot, `rxhtmlTag` is the regex `/<(?!area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)(([a-z][^\/\0>\x20\t\r\n\f]*)[^>]*)\/>/gi` which is mathcing the `<div data-h='/>` and replacing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is the result from a RegEx substitution in the [html()](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=html) function.

Before doing anything with the value, jQuery does a quick substituion, filtering out anything it sees as non-valid. This is done by this line:

```
value = value.replace(rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>");
```

[The RegEx is](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L37):

```
rxhtmlTag = /<(?!area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)(([a-z][^\/\0>\x20\t\r\n\f]*)[^>]*)\/>/gi
```

And indeed, when only running this substitution, you get:

```js
var str = "<div data-h='/>'>jquery</div>";

str = str.replace(/<(?!area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)(([a-z][^\/\0>\x20\t\r\n\f]*)[^>]*)\/>/gi, "<$1></$2>");

alert(str);
```

Comment: Roland is right. Raw text refers to elements that accept raw text as content, such as script, style, textarea and title. Also, the specific string that is disallowed starts with `</` (the first two characters of an end tag), not `/>` (the shortcut self-closing syntax from XML).

Comment: (Roland seems to have deleted his comments.) The fragment `<div data-mine="/>">content</div>` is [valid HTML](https://checker.html5.org/?showsource=yes&doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%3C%21DOCTYPE+html%3E%3Ctitle%3E%2F%3E+in+attribute+value%3C%2Ftitle%3E%250A%3Cdiv+data-mine%3D%22%2F%3E%22%3Econtent%3C%2Fdiv%3E). (If you look at that validator link, you'll notice that the unescaped /> in the title element also doesn't raise any errors.)

Comment: To me, this is a bug in jQuery?

Comment: @tpower If this answer helped you, please accept it.